# Online Dynamics CRM Plugin Registration tool stopped to work

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

Recently (I presume, after introducing new login system using user@a.onmicrosoft.com) CRM SDK PluginRegistration tool stopped to work. Has anybody solution for that?

Comment: Microsoft do, I would imagine.

Comment: Please provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another thread to the same issue, and it looks like changing your Discovery URL will get everything squared away.

http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/crm/thread/039f9483-f1c2-4718-9c56-3f7d66cbea26

Comment: there is a good pointing except that discovery url can be taken from online crm instance itself and for instance in our case it was https://disco.crm4.dynamics.com instead of https://disco.crm.dynamics.com